# Gorm belongs-to relation with same foreignKey and referenced primary key name

Tags: go, grails-orm, auto-migration

Gorm have a strange bug when i'm unable to use automatic table creation. If i use same primary key field name as referenced foreign key from other table, it can't handle it properly.

Working example - `User.ComID` references to `Company.ID`:

```golang
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    ComID string
    Company Company `gorm:"foreignKey:ComID;references:ID"`
}
type Company struct {
    ID   string `gorm:"primaryKey"`
}
```

produces followin auto-migration sequence with:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "companies" ("id" text,"name" text,PRIMARY KEY ("id"))
CREATE TABLE "users" ("id" bigserial,"created_at" timestamptz,"updated_at" timestamptz,"deleted_at" timestamptz,"name" text,"com_id" text,PRIMARY KEY ("id"),CONSTRAINT "fk_users_company" FOREIGN KEY ("com_id") REFERENCES "companies"("id"))
```

but if i change ID of second table to `ComID`

```golang
type User struct {
    ComID string
    Company Company `gorm:"foreignKey:ComID;references:ComID"`
}
type Company struct {
    ComID   string `gorm:"primaryKey"`
}
```

everything stops working. Gorm try to execute incorrect sql code, table users does not exists at that moment.

```
CREATE TABLE "companies" ("com_id" text,"name" text,PRIMARY KEY ("com_id"),CONSTRAINT "fk_users_company" FOREIGN KEY ("com_id") REFERENCES "users"("com_id"))
```

Any ideas how i can supply gorm with correct description (except creating different column names)?

If it matters, the dialect of sql is Postgres in this case.

Answer (score 0):

gorm don't allow it:

references include self fields

you can change the code: relationship.go line 559

```
            if ref.OwnPrimaryKey {
                constraint.Schema = ref.ForeignKey.Schema
                constraint.ReferenceSchema = rel.Schema
            } else {
                constraint.Schema = rel.Schema
                constraint.ReferenceSchema = ref.PrimaryKey.Schema
            }
```

to

```
            if false {
                constraint.Schema = ref.ForeignKey.Schema
                constraint.ReferenceSchema = rel.Schema
            } else {
                constraint.Schema = rel.Schema
                constraint.ReferenceSchema = ref.PrimaryKey.Schema
            }
```

and if you run

```
db.Debug().AutoMigrate(User{})
```

you will see it:

```
CREATE TABLE "companies" ("com_id" text,"name" text,PRIMARY KEY ("com_id"),CONSTRAINT "fk_users_company" FOREIGN KEY ("com_id") REFERENCES "users"("com_id"))
```